# Icefaces 3.1 getting session timeout on first partial submit

Tags: session-timeout, icefaces-3

I have a single page application in icefaces 3 using Mojarra 2.1.6

The application is like this there are 3 radio buttons on the top and a data table with input fields.

The problem is that when I open the site for the first time in the browser the the site opens ... but the moment there is a partial submit from any part of the page , the session expires. After the page is reloaded the page works smoothly

The site was running peacefully in 1.8.2 but we are thinking if we should upgrade to icefaces 3

If you need any other info please let me know

edit

I solved it using a workaround but the issue is still there

workaround is to call the page using a index.jsp page this prevents the above error

Answer (score 0):

With ICEfaces 3/JSF2 you sould not use `partialSubmit` anymore, use the new `<f:ajax />` tag instead.

And did you read the page on the ICEfaces Wiki about the compatibility to 1.8.x? http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/ICEfaces+1.x+Compatibility

Try to migrate to the new ACE-Components, or use the normal JSF-Components(`<h:... />`). The ICE-Components are not built for JSF2 and should be avoided, i have had of problems with them in JSF2 applications.