# PartialSubmit not working in Icefaces 3.3

Tags: jsf-2, icefaces, icefaces-3, icefaces-1.8

I have a project to Migrate icefaces 1.8 to 3.3  . This is the first time I am doing this conversion process and facing lots of difficulties. I am very new to Icefaces, so pardon me if I ask any silly questions.
I can able to run the project in Icefaces 3.3 But some of the functionality was not working properly .I’m facing issue in Partial submit .Can you please provide the alternative code for the below.

```
<ui:define name="content">
        <ice:form id="stackForm" partialSubmit="true">
            …….
    <ice:commandLink  actionListener="#{item.userObject.selectPanelStackPanel}"  
                      action="#{tree.planNodeSelected}" partialSubmit="true">
        <ice:outputText id="treeContentTxt" value="#{item.userObject.plan }" rendered="#{item.leaf}" />
        <f:param name="param1" value="#{item.userObject.param1}" />
        <f:param name="param2" value="#{item.userObject.param2}" />
        <f:param name="param3" value="#{item.userObject.param3}" />
        <f:param name="param4"  value="#{item.userObject.param4}" />
    </ice:commandLink>

    ……..    
</ice:form>
</ui:define>
```

Comment: What issue are you facing? Please be more specific. I mean how was it like before migrating? And how is it like after migrating?

Comment: Thank you for your response .Currently in icefaces 1.8 on the click of command link, Panel grid will be shown without refreshing the page .After migrating to Icefaces 3.3 while click of the command link ,the entire page is getting  submitted (Ajax call is not working).

Comment: What do you have in the action? Are you returning a string of outcome?

Comment: Let me make it clearer .I’m having two panel inside the panel stack .let say panel 1 and panel 2. Panel 1 will having some default text and Panel will have the calendar component.  By default panel one will be selected .when I click on the command link, the action listener will change the flag to select panel 2 and action method will fire the business logic and return a string of outcome as the same page.

Comment: .I don’t know, I came to from one of the link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13031027/icefaces-3-1-getting-session-timeout-on-first-partial-submit   mention like partial submit won’t work in icefaces 3.3

Comment: Did you try return null for your action? Also you need to use view scoped bean for your item or whatever bean in the view depending on your requirement.

Comment: Regarding the partialSubmit not working, I myself used partialSubmit in a lot of places with Icefaces 3.3. Posting some more code always helps and if you want to get an answer. We need to identify the mistake which may possibly be in the rest of your xhtml code or the java code.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will cover all your questions:
http://www.icesoft.org/wiki/display/ICE/Converting+ICEfaces+1.8+Applications+to+ICEfaces+3

Example: Transform all of your ice:form to h:form... Mind the differences with header namespaces and so on...

Comment: OP needs a solution, not a white paper!

Comment: Thank you sabrina, I had already done the changes as the part of icefaces 3.3 migration link shared by you